# If there is some way to use single NSManagedObjectContext per app both for reading and writing?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I used **CoreData + MagicalRecord** in iOS app. Application has many multithreading issues related to both reading and writing at a time, from different threads. Also one requirement exist to quick reading of rather big amounts data. According to this only **one NSManagedObjectContext** is used. To achieve this goal some kind of Manager was created with @synchronization's usage. Main problem locates in the read-write conflict on NSManagedObjects that were retrieved by the Manager. So if I access to one property of NSManaged object in on thread and on another I read in the Manager the same info - application will crash. How can I solve this problem with single NSManagedObjectContext? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I understand that multiple contexts for one per thread will solve this problem. But I need to transfer changes and objects between threads too often and it will be not so quick as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using same NSManagedObjectContext between different threads is so dangerous. I could cause so many unexpected states and crashes.

If you want to transfer changes and objects between threads, following steps may help you

Consider you want to transfer from context A to B

1) Register for following NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification with context A.

eg . [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:delegete selector:@selector(mergeContext:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:contextA];

2) In your delegate class implement merge context

-(void)mergeContext:(NSNotification *) nofify
{

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {

    [contextB mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:nofify];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [contextB save:&error];
}
else
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeContext:) withObject:nofify waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

}

3) Where were u have to transfer data from context A to B do a same operation. This will trigger the merge operation

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    [contextA save:&error];
```

4)At the end of thread don't forget to un-regester the notification

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:delegate name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:contextA];

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks